# PyCharm Error when setting remote interpreter -> Run Error: Jupyter server process failed to start due to path mismatch issue

Tags: python, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2, pycharm

I am trying to setup remote development on PyCharm. For this, I want to make changes locally and execute the code on remote Amazon EC2 instance with a remote interpreter. I had done the following configuration of the project, but I am getting run error when I try to execute a ipython file created locally.

> Cannot run program "stfp://<remote server hostname>/<remote server host>:<remote interpreter path>" (in directory <local folder directory>): error=2, No such file or directory.

It seems it should open <remote folder directory> instead of <local folder directory> when running the program. I read through multiple setup instructions but could not get this fixed. I am attaching configuration below.

Can you please help me with what could be wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating PyCharm to 2022.3 can fix the issue. This seems to be related to an unstable older version.